# How to make a loop in C++ that runs a time counter and allows for user input simultaneously (non-blocking user input)

Tags: c++, nonblocking, kbhit

So, what I am trying to do is **create a function in C++ that allows the user to input anything and everything into a string for a set amount of time** (say, ten minutes (or even one)) (**and KEEP all the stuff they inputted,** btw. I'm trying to design a game to help NaNoWriMo participants or authors in general to push them to write, so keeping everything is essential) **and then doesn't allow for anymore input to be appended.** This sounded easy at first, but five hours of Googling proved otherwise.

First, I figured that I could just append repeatedly until time ran out or something. Observe:

```
int main() //testing
{
    string str;
    string app = " ";
    getline(cin, app);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        cout << i << endl;
        str = " ";
        getline(cin, str);
        app.append(str);
    }

    cout << app;
}
```

But then I realized, *duh,* that the loop won't check the condition again until the user presses enter. Bothersome. Same with my clever idea of a character. I needed a loop that updated with every character typed (or every second past), no matter how long the user takes to type another one.

So, then I was like, "Well, stopping at every space and updating the time should work well enough, yeah?"

This is when I began to discover that C++ does not play well with parsing strings, or reading input as it gets it. I thought about appending each *character,* since that's pretty easy to find a space with, but it *still* waits for the user.

Frustrated, I wondered if there was a way to have a program run simultaneously while getting user input so that once time ran out (using time(null), *time passes,* time(null) and subtracting the two variables to get the seconds elapsed).

Turns out, there is! (I knew there *had* to be, considering all the computer programs and games that use this principle, but I'm pretty new to programming (I learned *functions* this last Wednesday, to give you an idea), so I didn't know *what*.)

The first functions I stumbled on were curses and ncurses, but I quickly discovered that that really wasn't a viable option for what I want to do (since I hear it does rather funny things to cout).

*Then* I stumbled on kbhit, which recognizes when keys are pressed on the keyboard. [This blog](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/) seems to be promising, and probably what I want to do, but I'm not sure what language it's written in . . . all I know is that it doesn't play well with my C++ IDE. I have no idea how to make it play nice with C++.

So, a reiteration of what I would like:

**A loop that contains a simultaneous execution of a time counter and user input (to a string), but terminates (ceases to let user input further to the string) when the time runs out.** (All without doing funny things to the rest of my program, like ncurses would.)

Additionally: I run Windows 8 (the bane of my existence) and I use Code::Blocks as my IDE.

*Or, if you've got it, somewhere this question has already been answered. That would actually be great. It would just make me feel silly that I couldn't find it.*

(Here are some places I looked at along the way:

[User input while program still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257777/user-input-while-program-still-running)

[How do I read input from standard input until a space or a tab is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054399/how-do-i-read-input-from-standard-input-until-a-space-or-a-tab-is-pressed)

[Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed) )

(The game I'm trying to create, (which is totally not very far yet; I started on it last night), in case you were curious: https://github.com/Rowan-Law/Dungeon-Crawl/blob/master/Source%20Code )

Comment: In standard C++, when `std::cin` is waiting for the user to press enter, then there's no way you can interrupt it. All you can do is check the elpased time after the user has pressed enter (you don't even need multi-threading for that). If you need more control over the low-level operations involved with getting text input on the console, then you need to tell us which OS and compiler you use.

Comment: And btw, if you want this much control, then you will probably soon want to switch to a GUI program anyway.

Comment: [ReadConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do what it seems like you want on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd get a pretty close approximation of what you want in C++17 using threading. The only hiccup is that the user can still type after the time limit, it just won't be saved.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <mutex>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_bool done = false;
std::mutex cout_mutex{};

void Timing(std::chrono::seconds length) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto end = start + length;
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while(now < end) {
        now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        done = false;
    }
    done = true;
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << "\nTime's up! Any unsaved input will be lost." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string str{};
    std::string app{};

    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    //This can be any duration you want.
    std::thread t = std::thread(Timing, 30s);
    t.detach();
    while(!done) {
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        if(!done) {
            app.append(str + '\n');
        }
    }
    std::cout << app;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to make a thread for the time and then just keep updating the string until the time thread returned

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading is the solution. At a base-level, C++ console applications using `std::cin` only update on enter (as both I and Christian Hackl pointed out), so without threading, what I wanted to do is impossible.

I know this question is pretty old, but I hope this answer saves some other newbie a bunch of time scouring the web for an answer that doesn't exist!